# Call function in .js file

Tags: jquery, callback, call

I have a big problem with this Function:

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.scrollPagination = function(options) {
function getData() {
                $.post('load.php', {
                    action: 'scrollpagination',
                    number: $settings.nop,
                    offset: offset,
                }, function(data) {

                    // Change loading bar content (it may have been altered)
                    $this.find('.loading-bar').html($initmessage);

                    // If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error
                    if (data == "") {
                        $this.find('.loading-bar').html('<span class="label label-info">No News</span>');
                    }
                    else {

                        // Offset increases
                        offset = offset + $settings.nop;

                        // Append the data to the content div
                        $this.find('.content').append(data);

                        // No longer busy!  
                        busy = false;
                    }

                });

            }

            getData(); // Run function initially
  });
    }

})(jQuery);
```

(From: http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/01/scroll-pagination/)

I will call the Function "getData" in another HTML File.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#statustext').submit(function() {
                        ....
                        })
                                .done(function(data) {
                                    getData();
                                })
                                .fail(function() {
                                    ...
                                });
                        return false;
                    });
                });
```

But, isn't work. Can everybody help me?
I searched in Stackoverflow and Google, but I have found nothing.

Comment: try   .scrollPagination.getData()

Comment: Doesn't work.
.scrollPagination.getData() or scrollPagination.getData()

Comment: It's not within scope, so it's not accessible from outside the plugin

Answer (score 0):

(function($) {

```
$.fn.scrollPagination = function(options) {

    var settings = {
        nop     : 10, // The number of posts per scroll to be loaded
        offset  : 0, // Initial offset, begins at 0 in this case
        error   : '', // When the user reaches the end this is the message that is
                                    // displayed. You can change this if you want.
        delay   : 500, // When you scroll down the posts will load after a delayed amount of time.
                       // This is mainly for usability concerns. You can alter this as you see fit
        scroll  : true // The main bit, if set to false posts will not load as the user scrolls. 
                       // but will still load if the user clicks.
    }

    // Extend the options so they work with the plugin
    if(options) {
        $.extend(settings, options);
    }

    // For each so that we keep chainability.
    return this.each(function() {       

        // Some variables 
        $this = $(this);
        $settings = settings;
        var offset = $settings.offset;
        var busy = false; // Checks if the scroll action is happening 
                          // so we don't run it multiple times

        // Custom messages based on settings
        if($settings.scroll == true) $initmessage = '';
        else $initmessage = '';

        // Append custom messages and extra UI
        $this.append('<div class="content"></div><div class="loading-bar">'+$initmessage+'</div>');

        function getData() {

                        $("#loader").fadeIn(400).html('<img src="http://zingclub.in/images/loading.gif" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Loading Images');


            // Post data to ajax.php
            $.post('ajax.php', {
                category :$('#category').val(),
                category1:$('#category1').val(),
                subcat:$('#subcat').val(),
                area:$('#filter_area1').val(),
                action        : 'scrollpagination',
                number        : $settings.nop,
                offset        : offset,

            }, function(data) {

                // Change loading bar content (it may have been altered)
                $this.find('.loading-bar').html($initmessage);


                // If there is no data returned, there are no more posts to be shown. Show error
                if($('#filter_area1').val()!='empty')
                    {

                            $this.find('.content').html('');

                            $this.find('.content').html(data);


                    }
                else if(data == "") { 
                    $this.find('.loading-bar').html($settings.error);   
                }
                else {

                    // Offset increases
                    offset = offset+$settings.nop; 

                    // Append the data to the content div
                    $this.find('.content').append(data);

                    // No longer busy!  
                    busy = false;

                }   

            });

        }   

        if($('#filter_area1').val()!='empty')

                    {
                        var a=  $('#filter_area1');
                            $this.find('.content').hide.html(data)();
                            $a.append( data ).append( $loader.hide() );
                    }
                    else
                    {
        getData(); // Run function initially
                    }

        // If scrolling is enabled
        if($settings.scroll == true) {
            // .. and the user is scrolling
            $(window).scroll(function() {

                // Check the user is at the bottom of the element
                if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $this.height() && !busy) {

                    // Now we are working, so busy is true
                    busy = true;

                    // Tell the user we're loading posts
                    $this.find('.loading-bar').html('');

                    // Run the function to fetch the data inside a delay
                    // This is useful if you have content in a footer you
                    // want the user to see.
                    setTimeout(function() {

                        getData();

                    }, $settings.delay);

                }   
            });
        }

        // Also content can be loaded by clicking the loading bar/
        $this.find('.loading-bar').click(function() {

            if(busy == false) {
                busy = true;
                getData();
            }

        });

    });
}
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: Use this code i your java script file and in your php file use one div for loading